# Add Roles Upon Joining Server Discord js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Is there a way that I could make my bot add a role to a member upon joining the server? I want it to add "Member" role

What I have so far

```js
var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "MyRole");
message.member.addRole(role);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done so far? It's far easier to guide you in the right direction if you start off showing this ^!

Comment: Please show your code for us to see the problem and help

Comment: What version of DJS do you intend to use? You seem to be using v11

Comment: Im currently using DJS v13 as you can see in the question title

Comment: Was a little confused since `addRole` is a v11 method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to give roles to your members. One of the easiest ways is to just give the list of role IDs (in your case just one).

```js
message.member.roles.add(['role-id']);
```

Not sure if the bot's role matter anymore, but at one point bot's role on the server must be higher than the role given out. So make sure to do so.